# Flutter - how to change keyboard theme to dark?

Tags: flutter

I use dark theme for app, but keyboard which appears with `TextField` has white background and dark numbers (used keyboard type: TextInputType.number). How to change keyboard theme to dark?

```
theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith( ...
```

a minimal exaple

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Text Field Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        // primaryColor: Colors.black,
        // primaryColorLight: Colors.black,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: const EquipmentView(),
    );
  }
}

class EquipmentView extends StatelessWidget {
  const EquipmentView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
              onSubmitted: (value) {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems it works on real phone and doesn't work on emulator.

Comment: Yeah I can easily change the keyboard when dark mode is enabled/disabled but I want to know how to do it without giving the information to every single `TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class FooBar extends HookWidget {
  const FooBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final keyboardAppearance = usePlatformBrightness();

    return TextField(
      keyboardAppearance: keyboardAppearance,
    );
  }
}
```